# How do I turn on/off led with the same IR button?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, led

I'm trying to make the led switch on/off by the same case(): code.
But its not working could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried checking the current state and acting accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good if you add your sketch if you have one.

In principle, you have to create a boolean variable which keeps the current state of the LED. When you get an IR command, inside the IR button handler invert the state of the boolean. Than change the LED accordingly.

Something like:

Const/Global variable:

```
#define LED_PIN 8

int ledState;
```

In setup:

```
 ledState = FALSE;
 digitalWrite(LED_PIN, ledState);
```

In side loop:

```
case IR_BUTTON_CHANGE_LED:
   ledState = ledState == LOW ? HIGH : LOW; // Invert state
   digitalWrite(LED_PIN, ledState); // Set LED according to state
   break;
```